# Is it possible at this time to use Google's new GIDSignIn and make G+ queries/use GPPShare without having to sign in again?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus

My app signs the user in using GIDSignIn, it works perfectly and opens a webview within the app, thus ensuring the app won't get rejected for guideline 10.6.  However, the app also allows the user to share on socials including G+.  I can't find any way to share without using GPPNativeShareBuilder which bounces the user into Safari to sign in a second time.

Is there any link between these two frameworks?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you got any solution